# how to avoid calculate all distances in cluster to get most related posts in text clustering?

Tags: python, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis, text-classification

**In k-means clustering**

I have large number of samples in each cluster, so when i have new sample and i want to get nearest 10 posts to it,I have to calculate distance using euclidean or cosine or whatever which take a lot of time to calculate with this large number of samples within the cluster.
Is there is any way to set radios and use the new sample as center and get only values within this radios?

```
with open('Clustring4m.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    pickle.dump(km, fid)



new_post_label = km.predict(new_post_vec)[0]

similar_indices = (km.labels_==new_post_label).nonzero()[0]
similar = []
for i in similar_indices:
    #print(i)
    dist = sp.linalg.norm((new_post_vec - X_train[i]).toarray())
    similar.append((dist, df_train[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a library for *similarity search*?

These contain index structure to make neighbor searches faster.